# Installing Kiln on external drive on MacBook

Tags: node, setup, kiln

If I change path in file sharing in Docker and then run in Terminal:

```
DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1 docker run -v /volumes/Drive -p 8000:8000 obsidiansystems/tezos-bake-monitor:0.4.0  --pg-connection="host=host.docker.internal port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=my password ”
```

Will Kiln be installed on /volumes/Drive?

Comment: What do you mean by "Kiln be installed on my ...drive"? "Kiln" is a lot of things. It's a web server, static assets, tezos binaries (like the node, baker, etc.) and the storage used for those things.

Comment: I was referring to storage.

To override a configuration option, create an environment variable named REGISTRY_variable where variable is the name of the configuration option and the _ (underscore) represents indention levels. For example, you can configure the rootdirectory of the filesystem storage backend:

storage:
  filesystem:
    rootdirectory: /var/lib/registry
To override this value, set an environment variable like this:

REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY=/somewhere
This variable overrides the /var/lib/registry value to the /somewhere directory....what do you think?